# if missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed - day of week as number

Tags: r, na

I have the following code to identify the day of week as a number from my data set:

```
sapply(weekdays(as.Date(date), abbreviate=TRUE), 
     function(x) if(x=="Sun") 1 else 
                 if(x=="Mon") 2 else 
                 if(x=="Tue") 3 else 
                 if(x=="Wed") 4 else 
                 if(x=="Thu") 5 else 
                 if(x=="Fri") 6 else 
                 if(x=="Sat") 7 else 0)
}
```

But the problem i am having is that i must have blanks in my dates when i try to apply it using this formula:

```
d$dow <- myweekday(d$DateTime)
```

R throws this error up:

> Error in if (x == "Sun") 1 else if (x == "Mon") 2 else if (x == "Tue") 3 else if (x ==  : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

How do i proceed please? I tried to put another if command in the above (if X=="NA") 0 but this didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you format the code pieces in your question https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: you should use `wday()` function from package `lubridate` it does exactly that, with argument `label=FALSE`. It is also vectorised (no need for apply) and returns NA for anything wrong in input, might be better than `0` in a lot of cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems OK, apart from a single bracket at the end (copy paste error?)
You get an error because you probably you have some missing data in the input; this gives the same error message

```
sapply(weekdays(c(Sys.time(), NA), abbreviate=TRUE), function(x) 
  if(x=="Sun") 1 else 
    if(x=="Mon") 2 else 
      if(x=="Tue") 3 else 
        if(x=="Wed") 4 else 
          if(x=="Thu") 5 else 
            if(x=="Fri") 6 else 
              if(x=="Sat") 7 else 0)
```

The weekdays function gives an error if anything wrong is in the input (NA or something that doesn't match a date). You'd be better off with the `lubridate::wday()` function that already handles numeric day names:

```
library(lubridate)
wday(as.Date(date))
#### [1]  6 NA
```

You can then replace NAs with whatever you want.